# "Thermal blooming" - where does the term come from?

Tags: terminology, non-linear-optics

An important nonlinear effect during propagation of high-power lasers through air (and other material media, I think) is thermal blooming, where heating due to absorption of laser light changes the local refractive index, thus increasing the diffraction. As someone whose mother tongue is not English, I'd like to understand why it was named thermal **blooming**. Does it have something to do with flowers?!

Comment: This is not really a physics question, but I would guess it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*Thermal blooming
or defocusing occurs when. because of absorption,
a laser beam heats the liquid in its path. As the
liquid expands, the refractive index decreases; thus
**the beam creates for itself a diverging lens**.*" [emph added] [Source](https://pubs.aip.org/aip/apl/article-abstract/12/8/241/41024/TIME-DEPENDENCE-IN-THE-THERMAL-BLOOMING-OF-LASER?redirectedFrom=fulltext).

“*Thermal blooming of laser beams is the result of the nonlinear interaction of the laser radiation of the propagation path which is heated by absorption of a fraction of the radiation itself. **The term thermal blooming was initially applied to the expansion or ‘blooming’** of a CW beam propagating in a stationary liquid, but the term is now generally used to describe all self-induced thermal distortion of laser radiation.*” [emph added] [Source](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stampPDF/getPDF.jsp?tp=&arnumber=1455078&ref=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8=).

“*Although we stress in this Account the aspects
that are important for absorption measurements, there are also undesirable consequences of index
changes from thermal absorption. For high average powers, the **spreading or ‘thermal blooming’** in passing through solid windows or fluid cells may be significant even when these materials are relatively
transparent.*” [emph added] [Source](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ar50079a003?casa_token=L0yD7bwQrLEAAAAA:IEdR3y4zVvbBVrDMXe-0TjhyayRGYeveeKRNIt3fFyxlRvXsJHu4kY_UNY2DHZovUyxNLYcYwOb64YU).

Yes, the term is meant to evoke the growth of a flower bloom—in contrast to convergence to a point—as defocusing and divergence occur.